# Best solution to update last modified date -

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I have a Spring controller for adding different kind of elements to the parent items, when I update or add a new item I need to update the last modified date of his parent. My problem is that we call to many times this update last modified date service and I want to avoid this.
 Is there a better or more elegant way to solve this, then timers(Timer, TimerTask )  or 
ScheduledFuture, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

```
Timer updateLastModifiedDateTimer = timers.get(parentkey);
    if (updateLastModifiedDateTimer != null) {
        updateLastModifiedDateTimer.cancel();
    }
    TimerTask updateLastModifiedDateTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            getPresentationDAO().updateLastModifiedDate(owner, parentkey, System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    };
    updateLastModifiedDateTimer = new Timer(true);
    updateLastModifiedDateTimer.schedule(updateLastModifiedDateTask, updateDelay);
    timers.put(parentkey, updateLastModifiedDateTimer);
```

And I have something similar implemented with ScheduledFuture & ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing that in the presentation layer, and not in the service layer. And I understand even less why you're using a Timer to do that. Why don't you simply invoke `parent.setLastModifiedDate(System.currentTimeMillis())` in the service which adds a child to the parent?

Comment: why use a Timer here ? Has it been used to meet some specific purpose ?

Comment: It's in the service layer and I need to make an update on database each time and, I want to have a delay to see if I get a new update in this interval then cancel previous task and call update on database  only once.